# Youtube api v3 - how to retrieve comments marked as spam (with java)

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, information-retrieval

Is it possible to retrieve youtube comments marked as spam?

All I see is that is only possible marking a comment as spam, but I want to **retrieve** spam comments from youtube.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible

Answer (score 4):

You can set a comment's moderation status, call the '*commentThreads.list*' method to retrieve comments from the channel or video.Set the *moderationStatus* parameter's value to '*likelySpam*' to retrieve comment threads classified as likely to be spam. A comment thread can be included in the response if the top-level comment or at least one of the replies to that comment is considered likely to be spam.

Please refer to the Official Youtube Data API link below:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list

Comment: Before posting the question I tried to retrieve the moderation status of several videos and the result was 'null'.
Then I read that to retrieve the moderation status I needed the authorization of the author of the video, but now I can't find this information anymore. I'll try again with other videos.

Comment: Ok, all I get is error 400, Bad Request. Here's the code.
`CommentThreadListResponse videoCommentsListResponse = youtube.commentThreads()
                    .list("snippet, replies").setVideoId(videoId).setTextFormat("plainText")
                    .setMaxResults(100L).setModerationStatus("likelySpam").setOrder("relevance").execute();`
the problem may be that I wrote this part of code bad, or that I can't do this kind of request on the videos I used.

Comment: If needed, the error message:
"The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the <code>commentThread</code> resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid."

Comment: Update: I confirm that all the video comments I tried to retrieve had the moderationStatus null, nobody with likelySpam or other values.

Comment: I think that the moderationStatus parameter is for the video author to monitor his comment. If the author didn't set the comment moderation, the parameter is null.